# Which server Django is using?

Tags: python, django, server

After we installed the Django, we use the command:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

we can run a server, but I don't know the server is which server, and I searched the django directory, find the server is not in the directory:

```
aircraftdeMacBook-Pro:Django-1.11.2-py2.7.egg ldl$ cd django/
aircraftdeMacBook-Pro:django ldl$ ls
__init__.py bin     dispatch    shortcuts.pyc   utils
__init__.pyc    conf        forms       template    views
__main__.py contrib     http        templatetags
__main__.pyc    core        middleware  test
apps        db      shortcuts.py    urls
```

So, I have two questions:

1. The server is which web-server, and how can I find its location?
2. If we finish the application, if we use the web-server as the python-web's web-server(means why not apache or nginx)?
3. The port default is 8000, how to change to the 80?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django `runserver` is a **local dev server**, should not be used in production... APACHE AND NGINX are different things.

Django provides a simple [WSGI server](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-WSGI_APPLICATION) as a dev server.

Also id guess you have not looked inside the django docs because what you are looking for is right [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#runserver)

> Examples of using different ports and addresses¶
>
> Port 8000 on IP address 127.0.0.1:
>
> django-admin runserver Port 8000 on IP address 1.2.3.4:
>
> django-admin runserver 1.2.3.4:8000 Port 7000 on IP address 127.0.0.1:
>
> django-admin runserver 7000

Answer (score 3):

1) Django provides a default wsgi server as @sach20 mentioned.

2) The django server should be used for development. I personally use nginx and gunicorn to run my server. You can find a tutorial on how to set on up here:
[Tutorial](http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/06/09/django-nginx-gunicorn-virtualenv-supervisor/)

3) You can run:

> python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80

You can substitute 80 with any port you want to use.

Comment: hows this different than my answer ?

Comment: @WilomGfx It isn't. I submitted just a bit after you did.

Answer (score 1):

Django provides a default wsgi development server

Comment: So, I can not use it to be the distribute web-server for python,alright? and how can I find the location of it?